# spring data mongodb group by

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring data Mongodb in my project and refer the below classes for my query on grouping the results:

**Student class:**

```
@Document(collection = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    //other fields

    //getters & setters

}
```

**StudentResults (dto):**

```
public class StudentResults {

    private String firstName;

    private List<String> studentIds; //I need List<Student> here

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public List<String> getStudentIds() {
        return studentIds;
    }

    public void setStudentIds(List<String> studentIds) {
        this.studentIds = studentIds;
    }
}
```

**StudentServiceImpl class:**

```
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public List<StudentResults> findStudentsGroupByFirstName() {
        TypedAggregation<Student> studentAggregation = 
               Aggregation.newAggregation(Student.class,
               Aggregation.group("firstName").
               addToSet("id").as("studentIds"),
               Aggregation.project("studentIds").
               and("firstName").previousOperation());

        AggregationResults<StudentResults> results = mongoTemplate.
             aggregate(studentAggregation, StudentResults.class);

        List<StudentResults> studentResultsList = results.getMappedResults();

        return studentResultsList;
    }
}
```

Using the above code, I am able to retrieve the `List<String> studentIds` successfully, but I need to retrieve `List<Student> students` using `Aggregation.group()`? Can you help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your `TypedAggregation` part to below and add `students` field to `StudentResults`

```
 TypedAggregation<Student> studentAggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Student.class,
               Aggregation.group("firstName").
               push("$$ROOT").as("students"));
```

[$$ROOT](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables) will push the whole document.

Update:

```
TypedAggregation<Student> studentAggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Student.class,
              Aggregation.group("firstName").
                 push(new BasicDBObject
                       ("_id", "$_id").append
                       ("firstName", "$firstName").append
                       ("lastName", "$lastName")).as("students"));
```

Comment: Is there any other alternative without using `$$ROOT`?

Comment: okay, thanks, how do I add group by with multiple fields to the above i.e., firstname and lastname?

Comment: Np. You can try something like `Aggregation.group("firstName", "lastName")`

Comment: tried push the column , but am getting column value multiple time (which is equal to the number of times in the count)
{
    "group": "[ \"test\" , \"test\" , \"test\"]",
    "count": 3  }

Comment: @Anand Use addToSet for unique values instead of push.

Comment: @SagarVeeram - Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056287/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-expected-unique-result-or-null-but-got-more ?