# Mongodb - java - retrieve distinct values of multiple fields

Tags: java, mongodb, field, distinct, distinct-values

I have a collection with repeated values for columns in the documents.  I want to query for distinct values of multiple fields(System, subsystem) combination. Below is a sample data:

```
"System" : "training", "subsystem": "user", "ccid": "post", ret: 0
"System": "training", "subsystem": "user", "ccid": "test", ret: 1
"System": "training", "subsystem ":"cour", "ccid":"sample", ret:0
```

I tried to use the aggregate from the other links, but it's not resolving in java for me. Could you please share me a sample java code using aggregate or map-reduce or any of the suitable methods

Comment: Have you tried using [$group](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#-group--aggregation-)

Comment: Could you please share the java syntax of aggregate group for this scenario? I tried, but couldn't get the correct syntax

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814325/spring-data-mongodb-group-by

Comment: @Joe: I don't have a class defined for the structure.  Could you share me a simple java query including aggregate group of 2 fields and projection fields?

Comment: I have formed this query:   cursor1= CollSubsystem.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.match(filter),Aggregates.project(SubSystemFields))).iterator() ;   In order to add group iteria, it's expecting BSON Format, i tried addfields also -> that's expecting field format. Please advise.